# In Brave, what was the bond that Merida tore with her pride?

Tags: brave

The witch's cauldron offers the following advice for reversing the spell that turned Merida's mother into a bear.

> *Fate be changed, look inside.
>
>   **Mend the bond torn by pride***

**What was the bond that was torn?**

Was it the tapestry, Merida's relationship with her mother, the rift created between the four clans or something else entirely?

Comment: All of the above?

Comment: @Kevin - I'm assuming the makers had one specific one in mind

Comment: They don't need to have had one specific one in mind. The problem to solve was the pride, in the process of fixing that, everything else came together. The point of the story is Merida's willingness to mend bonds, whereas Mordu was consumed by his own pride.

Comment: @DariM - Except that it says "bond" (singular), not bonds (plural).

Comment: @Valorum maybe it is an abstract metaphore, which would apply to anything that was broken by pride, since the point was to choose humility and diplomacy over pride ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the tie-in novel *[Disney Pixar Brave](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13573464-brave-big-golden-book)*, the bond that was torn by pride was the emotional bond between mother and daughter. It explicitly notes that Merida's original assumption (that the tapestry she cut needed to be fixed) wasn't the bond.

> At the Ring of Stones, **Merida realized she had to “mend the bond torn
> by pride," as the Witch’s message had told her. That meant returning
> to the castle and mending the family tapestry she had torn!** Mother and
> daughter headed home as fast as they could.

but

> The battle won, Merida wrapped the mended
> tapestry around Elinor. **But nothing happened.**
> "I don’t care what you are,” she cried. “You’re
> still my mum. I love you." Merida buried her face
> in Elinor's fur and wept as dawn began to break.
> As she wept, Merida felt a hand stroke her hair.
> She looked up. Her mother, back to her old self,
> was smiling down ar her. **The bond between them
> had been repaired. The spell was broken.**

This is backed up by another tie-in book;  *[Brave: Little Golden Book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13573461-brave-little-golden-book?from_search=true&from_srp=true&qid=FCKusD1uPq&rank=1)*

> Even though the tapestry was fixed, Elinor was still a bear.
>
> Merida threw her arms around her mother. “I want you back, Mum,” she
> said, “I love you.”  **At those words, her mother changed back into the
> queen!**

And the young reader book [*Brave: A mother's love*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13641928-a-mother-s-love?from_search=true&from_srp=true&qid=YUXGaD2ZTG&rank=1)

> The queen is
> human again!
> **Love has
>
> broken the spell.**

And a first person perspective in *[Merida's Wish](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18925312-merida-s-wish?from_search=true&from_srp=true&qid=0oXvrfE8YQ&rank=1)*

> Under the tapestry, I suddenly felt a hand stroking my hair. It was a human hand. My mother’s hand. I looked up into my mother’s face. She was smiling at me. She was no longer a bear—she was Elinor, the queen. My mum.
>
> Mum!” I cried as she laughed. **I loved my mum, no matter what. That was
>
> all it had taken to undo the spell and repair the bond we had.** We hugged and laughed and cried. Mum covered my face with kisses.